# blazor hybrid blazorwebview mixed mode http content and untrusted ssl certificate problem

Tags: c#, https, blazor, maui

i have a video tag and android app works in local intranet.
my server is ubuntu and using for hls streaming.
when trying with hls.js stream http://192.168.195.176:8080/hls/stream.m3u8
because of http , blazorwebview does not allow it to load.

i installed letsencrypt certificate with dns challenge and got certificates for ex: xxx.xyz domain

now when i hls stream in blazorwebview with:
https://192.168.195.176/hls/stream.m3u8
certificates are untrusted.. so i again cant stream it..

i tried network_security_config.xml and applied it to android manifest as:
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"

and the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.195.176</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <!-- Trust preinstalled CAs -->
            <certificates src="system" />
            <!-- Additionaly trusted user added CAs -->
            <certificates src="user"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

not worked..
then i tried

```
        private void blazorWebView_BlazorWebViewInitialized(object sender, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.BlazorWebViewInitializedEventArgs e)
        {
#if ANDROID
            
            if(e.WebView.Settings.MixedContentMode != Android.Webkit.MixedContentHandling.AlwaysAllow)
            {
                e.WebView.Settings.MixedContentMode = Android.Webkit.MixedContentHandling.AlwaysAllow;
                
          }
#endif
        }
```

again not worked for both http and https.
so there are 400 android clients in local network which does not have access to internet.
i have to serve hls streaming..
help needed

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand your scenario. Apparently something isn't working but you haven't provided any error messages/stack traces nor provided any other details about what is wrong. You mentioned getting certificates signed by letsencrypt but apparently you are working in an internal network and using private IP addresses to connect, but private IP addresses and letsencrypt don't go together.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the problem still exists in Maui, but I had problems with LetsEncrypt certificates in on of my CSharp apps on Android. It was the HttpClient which is based on the boring-ssl library, have a look at: https://github.com/martinstoeckli/SilentNotes/issues/111